# Write special masked TextBox for WPF

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

I want to develop a custom user control in WPF which has some sort of mask. this functionality is very like the one provided in many online applications where u enter your credit card number and next time whenever u sign in to your account u see only last for digits of the card number (something like *******4587) but while I display data in this way I want to keep real value unchanged so inside binding I will access full data.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
string originalNumber = textBoxOriginalNumber.Text;
int numberOfDigits = textBoxOriginalNumber.Text.Length;
string hidden = new String('*', numberOfDigits-4);
textBoxModifiedNumber.Text = hidden + originalNumber.Remove(0, numberOfDigits-4);
```

It's is not an elegant solution but will help you if anybody else give you a better solution. Basically, it takes the original credit card number, counts how many digits it has, removes the "n-4" first digits, then show the * symbol "n-4" times plus the four last digits. This will work no matter how many digits the original number has.

Additionally, I'm not sure if a mask (or the Regex suggested by the other user bellow) would work because (if I understood it well) it would replace the whole number, instead of show the last 4 digits.

Comment: It is not elegant solution I agree we should also note that VISA cambers are 16 digits length but there is also 15 digit length credit cards so this solution will not work as what it does is introduces extra variable. that is not bad but is there better solution? for example using masks?

Comment: I modified my answer based in your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx) with \d to indicate a digit

i.e.

```
var digits = new Regex(@"\d");
modifiedNumber = digits.Replace(originalNumber, "*");
```

Or if you want to update the whole set of numbers except for the last group

```
@"\d{4}-"
```

Comment: this is really good starting point I think but it will replace all numbers and will not leave last 4 digits visible. What I think is to create attached property and bind that to ViewModels CardNumber property or. I understand that this is not a good security point So I think I will just create private variable inside class and keep real number there and on its public getter I will return Formated number like ####-####-####-5887 so I if I can use regex to achieve that it would be perfect

Comment: this actually works but no formatting like ####-#### just plance ######
`
number.Substring(number.Length - 4)
                .PadLeft(number.Length, '*');
`

Comment: Updated with all numbers except tge last group matcher

Comment: that better now but it does not allow - between every 4 symbols so there must be extra step needed. I provided my own version below please have a look and tell me what u think.

Answer (score 1):

OK here is the way I resolved that issue. after working with Card numbers I wanted to work with ID and SN numbers as well so what I did was just wrote little method which takes in string and returns masked value here it is in case someone needs this in feature.

```
    public static string GetMaskedNumber(string unsecuredNumber, char maskChar)
    {
        return unsecuredNumber.Substring(unsecuredNumber.Length - 4)
                     .PadLeft(unsecuredNumber.Length - 6, ' ')
                     .PadLeft(unsecuredNumber.Length, maskChar);
    }
```